# Load Multiple Cordova Micro Apps inside Native IOS apps

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have to load multiple cordova apps based on user access in Native IOS app.
I want to load the zip files dynamically on app launch and store them in Documents or Libraries folder and then unzip these files, then I'm trying to load cordova views directly using below code in my view controller

```
CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
viewController.wwwFolderName=@"www";
viewController.startPage=@"abc.html";
viewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

But the problem is that the wwwFolderName is not working if I point dynamically to  Documents or Library folder it only accepts root folders which are shipped with the app, so I want to know how should I achieve this use case.

Comment: it's possible to load html content from Documents or Library, but CDVViewController.wwwFolderName is not prepared to load files from there. You can search some "content sync" plugins that download html and load it and check how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, here is an example, where YOUR_APP_PATH is string path to the directory, where you want to store you application sources, and YOUR_SEARCH_PATH is NSLibraryDirectory or NSDocumentsDirectory

```
- (void)openApp     
    NSString *filePath = [self directoryToApp:YOUR_APP_PATH forSearchPath:YOUR_SEARCH_PATH];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest *request    = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url
                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                       timeoutInterval: 20.0];
    [self.webView loadRequest:appReq request;
}

- (NSURL *)directoryToApp:(NSString *)appPath forSearchPath:(NSSearchPathDirectory)searchPath{
    NSString *basePath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory:searchPath].absoluteString;
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[basePath stringByAppendingString:appPath]];
}

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory:(NSSearchPathDirectory)searchPath
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory: searchPath
                                                   inDomains: NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let your wwwFolderName be following:

```
viewController.wwwFolderName=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"file://%@/www", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
```

this will point the start directory to your www folder inside document directory.